# Where is the damage mechanic defined?

Tags: combat, damage, valiant-universe-rpg

I have read through [the core rules for Valiant Universe RPG](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=20380) a couple of times now, and recently, having started to actually play it (online) I realised - there's no point in the book where it comes out and directly / explicitly states **how and when to allocate damage due to combat** ("Action").

The assumption *seems* to be "win the Action roll, do the stated damage (usually a flat number) to your opponent". But it is never stated anywhere.

Can anyone else find this, either in the book or [maybe in a QSR PDF or something](http://www.catalystgamelabs.com/valiant/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to organize the pertinent segments from the full rulebook in a way that makes sense, and bolded key bits:

---

### Weapons Damage & When It is Applied

Page 55:

> Most Valiant Universe characters start each Event with a default set of weapons. These are listed on the Dossier along with the **amount of damage they do when used successfully against a target**, and their range bracket.

Page 56:

> - Normal weapons do 2 points of damage
> - Larger, heavier weapons may do 4 points of damage
> - Rare, extremely dangerous, or special weapons may do 6
> - In place of a static Damage Value, a die can be assigned, which is rolled every time the weapon strikes a target to determine damage: only use D4 or D6. Weapons with higher variable damage are extremely rare or unpredictable.

---

### Powers That Act as Weapons

Page 45:

> Remember that Powers that act as weapons can have additional stats here. Let’s take a look at Flamingo’s Dossier (see pp. 96-97). Her Pyrokinesis Power is a weapon and so it has “(Weapon)” next to the name in the Powers portion of the character Dossier, which directs the player to both the Fireblast and Immolate stats in the Weapon section. These two sections combine to provide all the details a player needs to use this attack. In this case specifically the player rolls a D8 (alongside the appropriate Stat Die as determined by the LN) when attacking with either “weapon” (as noted in the Powers section), with the range of the Power determined by which the player chooses to use. **If an attack is successful the player rolls either a D4 or D6 to determine damage** (as noted in the Weapons section).

---

### How Damage is Applied

Page 55:

> Whenever a character takes damage, **the damage is first applied to the Armor column of the Dossier. Once all Armor pips are marked off, damage then begins to apply to the Health column**.

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer, even though it more or less confirms to me that indeed, the book never actually comes out and says "if you win the contested Action roll, you do X amount of damage to your opponent".